# Copy data from Synapse instance to another instance

Tags: azure-synapse

Is there a way to copy data from all tables in a Synapse instance to another?

Considered Data Migration Assistant, but it doesn't allow to select Synapse as Source.

Also, I am considering to use Copy activity in a pipeline, but the number of tables is not small.

Answer (score 0):

[Copy Data Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-hello-world-copy-data-tool) can be used to copy data from Synapse to Synapse.

Answer (score 0):

You create a Synapse or ADF pipeline to achieve same.

**Step1:** Use Lookup activity or Script activity with a dataset Synapse SQL database table. Select Query option there and write query to get list all table names.

**Step2:** Use ForEach activity to iterate each table name.

**Step3:** Inside ForEach activity, use Copy activity. In the copy activity you can use parameterized datasets which dynamically to points to tables in Synapse SQL.